# Return JSON details of failed validation with Laravel 8

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

I'm creating an endpoint to store an Office with two fields: name, address.
When validation fails laravel returns status 200 and a welcome page. It should return 4xx and error details with JSON, shouldn't it? I tried to catch an exception (ValidationError) but I don't get the error details.

```php7
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $request->validate([
            'name' => 'required',
            'address' => 'required'
        ]);
        // if validation failed, 4xx?

        // logic to create a model here
        return $office; // everything fine, 201 and object details
    }
```

I'm testing it with unit test and postman:

```
    public function testValidationFailed()
    {
        $payload = [
            "wrongfield" => "Example Name"
        ];

        $response = $this->postJson('/api/offices/', $payload);
```

and with postman the content-type is application/json

EDITED
Postman was messing up the headers. httpie and curl get the correct response with this code and the accepted answer's.

Comment: are you sending the correct "accept" headers for json? the application needs to know you want json back

Comment: yes I think so. unit tests with  '$response = $this->postJson...' and postman with the headers. I'll add it to the question

Comment: You said it returns a 200 and the welcome page? Something must be definitely wrong there. The method you are showing never intends to show that, or any, view.

Comment: Are you sure that you are actually hitting this controller method? On a normal request (not json) if the validation fails, it should redirect back and with a status code 302 and flash the validation errors in the session.

Comment: yes, I checked it with xdebug. In a normal request it makes sense because I'd have a session but this is an API and there isn't any html form. however it's the first time I use Laravel and I might be confused

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `Validator` instead like so

```
$validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
      'name' => 'required',
      'address' => 'required'
]);

if ($validator->fails()) {
   return response()->json($validator->errors(), 404);
}
```

Or you can use `validator()` helper method

```
validator($request->all(), [
    'name' => 'required',
    'address' => 'required'
])->validate();
```

This will automatically validate and response back with errors and it also, works with web and api endpoints.

Comment: so it is expected to build the response manually with that if? it does work, i'm concerned about building it correctly. Did you write 404 because there is a built-in way of returning 400?

Comment: For the first way you will build a custom response as you wish, for second Laravel will build a response with status code `422` and validation error messages.